# Worst case of Shell Sort?

Tags: asymptotics

What is the worst case for Shell Sort?
I think worst case is an ordered set with the largest values in odd positions:
$$ 1,4,2, 16,8, ...$$

With $O(n(log$ ${n)}^2)$ complexity or $O(n^2)$? Actually, I think that the former one is correct as opposed to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences) in which it is claimed that the worst case is of Gap Sequences with complexity of $\Theta(n^2)$.